# Затруднение с считыванием массива из файла

Tags: c, файлы, функции

Необходимо реализовать процедуру ввода массива целочисленных чисел с создающегося в процессе работы программы файла. Написал функцию, которая, однако, не работает. Переменную размера массива я передаю через лок. переменную n в функцию, где она приобретает вид size. Сама функция требует приведения...Понимаю, что что-то не то. Функция вывода написанная аналогично работает хорошо.

```
//array.cpp
int input_arrayA_from_file(int *a,int size)
{ 
//int*  a = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int)); разве нужно?
FILE * f1;
fopen("test.txt", "r"); 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) fscanf(f1, " %d", a + i); 
fclose(f1); 
return 0; 
}


//Непосредственно main.cpp с локальными переменными (например n==size)
     case 2:
                     printf("Введите размерность массива A: ");
                     scanf("%i", &n);
                     // вызываемый прототип функции считывания с файла массива А
                  a = input_arrayA_from_file(*a, n);
     printf("-------Введите данные с файла test.txt, расположенного непосредственно в папке с программой-------");
```

Comment: Кроме того (надеюсь, что с `fopen` - это описка), даже как-то странно. `a = input_arrayA_from_file(*a, n);`, после чего `a` получает значение 0, ибо сказано в функции - `return 0;`... Что вы вообще хотите после этого? :)

Comment: Но и так тоже не получается: void input_arrayA_from_file(int *a,int size)
{ 
FILE * f1;
f1 = fread("test.txt", "r");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
 fscanf(f1, " %d", a + i); 
}
fclose(f1);

Comment: Ну вы же весь код не показываете, откуда знать, что такое ваше `a`?..

Comment: Попробуйте проверять вызовы на ошибки. Говорят, помогает, правда не всем.

Comment: А каким образом? Через командный запросы или через брэкпоинтер?